# std::exception subclass, string member variable

Tags: c++, string, exception

The following code works just fine:

```
#include <exception>

using namespace std;

class FileException : public exception { // error occurs here
    int _error;
    // string _error; <-- this would cause the error
public:
    FileException(int error);
    // FileException(string error);
    const char* what() const throw();
};
```

But as soon as I change the type of `_error` to string, the following compile error occurs:

> Exception specification of overriding function is more lax than base version

Comment: Derive from std::runtime_error. You can pass a string to its constructor and it will store it for retrial with what(). Thus you  do not need to manage a string.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The destructor of `std::string` is *not* no-throw, which causes the implicit destructor of `FileException` *not* no-throw either. But the destructor of `std::exception` is no-throw, thus there's a compiler error.

You could declare an explicit no-throw destructor:

```
virtual ~FileException() throw() {}
```

or just inherit from `std::runtime_error` instead of `std::exception`, which has a constructor that takes `std::string` input.

Comment: Using the second method, the error still presists...
However if I add the destructor the error is gone. Thanks

Comment: @alex: Did you inherit from runtime_error _and_ remove the string member?  You shouldn't need it.  Runtime_error already does everything for you.

Answer (score 6):

Simplify with:

```
// Derive from std::runtime_error rather than std::exception
// std::runtime_error (unlike std::exception) accepts a string as an argument that will
// be used as the error message.
//
// Note: Some versions of MSVC have a non standard std::exception that accepts a string
//       Do not rely on this.
class FileException : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    // Pass error msg by const reference.
    FileException(std::string const& error)
        // Pass the error to the standard exception
        : std::runtime_error(error)
    {}
    // what() is defined in std::runtime_error to do what is correct
};
```

Comment: Passing 'error.c_str()' to std::exception is an option if 'std::runtime_error' would be incorrect.

Comment: @MooingDuck: std::exception only has a default constructor and copy constructor. There is no constructor that takes a C-String. std::runtime_error takes a std::string or C-String as its parameter in its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I approve of the above method,

but  *g++*  seems to complain if
the *default constructor* is not present.

The following addition makes things work:

```
using namespace std;

class MyException : public runtime_error {
public:
  /* add the following line: */
  MyException() : runtime_error("MyException") { } // default constructor

  MyException( string const& error ) : runtime_error(error) { }  // ctor w/string
};
```

additionally, an exception list is easily created:

```
MyException FileNotFound ( "File Not Found" );
MyException ReadOnly     ( "ReadOnly"       );
MyException Unkown       ( "Unknown"        );

...
throw FileNotFound;
...
```

when catching these exceptions, if you don't need specificity catch them generically:

```
catch( runtime_error re) {  cout << "Runtime Error: " << re.what() << endl;  ... }
```

Since all MyExceptions decend from runtime_error this catches them all and
you won't miss any other runtime errors from the system either.

```
catch( exception e) {  cout << "exception: " << e.what() << endl;  ... }
```

catches them all.

In C++, you can also throw and catch any types  (int, booleans,pointers, etc.) Its sometimes simpler
to just throw/catch a string or an int within a function block.

Multiple classes should only throw and catch code library standard exceptions and their subclasses, (and all in the same manner), however, mostly for consistency and maintenance, but also because c++ compilers know how to optimize the exception mechanisms and linkages for them, and can generate intelligent warnings and errors about them, easing debugging.

"Error: "0x137F" is for IBM guys, not "*the third guy on the project this year*" ...